# How to create themed Material UI components inside of a library

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

We want to build an internal component library and want to build it on top of Material-UI. We want to create a custom Material-UI theme and apply it to all included components.

Currently I see these options:

1. wrap every exported component into a `ThemeProvider` (resulting in many ThemeProviders in the application using the library which sounds bad)
2. force the users of the library to wrap their application in a Provider exported from our library (which would include the ThemeProvider with the theme)
3. using only the `sx` property for styling the components (so not using a theme at all)

I was not able to find solutions to this problem in the Material-UI docs. Do I miss something or what would be the preferred option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you find this [How to customize doc](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/)? It's kind of buried in the Material UI customization docs. There's no need to wrap every individual component with a Theme Provider—you can wrap your entire app with it, and you should only need to do it in one place (unless I'm not understanding your specific use case).

As the doc linked above explains, there are several different levels of customization you could choose, depending on your needs:

**1. At the individual component level**

- for one-off customizations of components that won't be reused, use [the `sx` prop](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/)

**2. At the reusable component level**

- if you're planning to reuse some custom style overrides, apply them with [the `styled()` utility](https://mui.com/system/styled/)

**3. At the theme level**

- for styles that will be repeated throughout the UI, you can customize the theme at the component level by [overriding default component styles](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/), or at the theme level by [defining your own custom theme variables](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#theme-configuration-variables) to be used by all components

**4. At the baseline / global level**

- if you need to apply style overrides above and beyond the theme level (such as a CSS reset for baseline style preferences), you can use the [`<GlobalStyles />` component](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/#4-global-css-override)

I hope this helps! As you'll see from the use cases described, there really is no "preferred" way to customize—the library provides several options that are each ideal for different situations, and you'll probably discover that you need to use some combination of them all as you're building your UI.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I want to build an internal component library that encapsulates Material UI with the company theme. I don't want to push the users of my library to add a ThemeProvider to their App. I have no control over the applications where my library is used but I want to makes usages as simple as possible

Comment: but you pointed me to [`styled()`](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/) which I think is the solution after I found this [`createStyled()`](https://mui.com/system/styled/#create-custom-styled-utility)

Comment: using `styled()` or `createStyled()` would also require `ThemeProvider` to apply the theme to the existing MUI components, so I think I have to do this, if there is no other alternative to apply a theme to the MUI components

Comment: Ah ok, I think I understand your use case a bit more clearly (but I must admit that I don't fully understand why you wouldn't want to instruct the developer to wrap their app with the Theme Provider). Any customization at the theme level would require the Theme Provider, and if that's off the table, then I think the `sx` prop is probably ideal.

Comment: Ok thank you, ThemeProvider is not completely off the table, I was just searching for solutions that don't involve that