# React JS, MUI different kinds of styling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

What is the difference between all these styling methods that MUI provides us.

For example you can style with `useTheme`, `styled` which is similar to styled components , `makeStyles` and the other styling methods?

Can someone provide a detailed explanation of all the differences , use cases for each of them and when to use them ?

Comment: I would recommend to read the documentation. I'm 100% sure that you will find an answer there. Stackoverflow is not for these kind of questions.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77113567/22099179) to a similar question to get up to speed on all of the different styling and theming options in Material UI v5:

**1. At the individual component level**

- for one-off customizations of components that won't be reused, use [the `sx` prop](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/)

**2. At the reusable component level**

- if you're planning to reuse some custom style overrides, apply them with [the `styled()` utility](https://mui.com/system/styled/)

**3. At the theme level**

- for styles that will be repeated throughout the UI, you can customize the theme at the component level by [overriding default component styles](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/), or at the theme level by [defining your own custom theme variables](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#theme-configuration-variables) to be used by all components

**4. At the baseline / global level**

- if you need to apply style overrides above and beyond the theme level (such as a CSS reset for baseline style preferences), you can use the [`<GlobalStyles />` component](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/#4-global-css-override)

I hope this helps! As you'll see from the use cases described, there really is no "preferred" way to customize—the library provides several options that are each ideal for different situations, and you'll probably discover that you need to use some combination of them all as you're building your UI.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35138440)

Comment: Good call - updated!